# Why cast does not succeed?

Tags: c++, linux, endianness

I am trying this:

```
 if constexpr (Bo == ByteOrder::Network && sizeof(T) == 8)
    return reinterpret_cast<T &> 
  (be64toh(reinterpret_cast<make_unsigned_t<T>&>(val)));
 else if constexpr (Bo == ByteOrder::Host && sizeof(T) == 8)
    return reinterpret_cast<T &>(htobe64(reinterpret_cast<make_unsigned_t<T>&>(val)));
```

It results in:

```
error: invalid cast of an rvalue expression of type ‘__uint64_t {aka long unsigned int}’ to type ‘long int&’
     return reinterpret_cast<T &>(be64toh(reinterpret_cast<make_unsigned_t<T>&>(val)));
```

Comment: Because your be64toh function returns a rvalue and you cannot bind a rvalue to lvalue reference. Just cast it to T instead of T&

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an oversight:

Just casting to T instead of T & will work, since the function is returning an rvalue and cannot be bound to an lvalue.